# Installing Laravel in Docker Container

Tags: laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bitnami, wsl-2

Environment: Windows 11 + Docker Desktop 4.12.0

I've been digging this the entire morning. There doesn't seem to be a way of installing Laravel in a Docker image. You must `curl` it in your WSL2 distro. Trying the command `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` in a Docker container command-line immediately returns the dreaded `Docker is not running` error message

Some suggest that I need to turn on my "WSL2 integration" checkbox in Docker Desktop settings, but that didn't help.

So what if I download the official Ubuntu image from Docker Hub, run it as a container. Can I download (`curl`) Laravel in that container?

And while we are here, how does the [Bitnami Laravel image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/laravel) differ from the standard procedure given in Laravel documentation? I like it because I can download it as a *normal* Docker image and create as many containers as I want, but I'm unsure how this connects or contrasts with the official Laravel method.

Comment: https://laravel.build/example-app is to install [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail), that means you run it outside of a container to create an app that uses docker for development. There's other ways to install Laravel that don't use sail like e.g. `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app`

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, the `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` command downloads several Docker images including MariaDB, Redis, mailhog etc. and therefore needs Docker to be running on the host machine (which is not available inside a container, that's why you can't run the curl command there). Once downloaded, it creates a new container containing (no puns intended) one container for each of these images. You can also customize the list of images/containers that your Laravel application needs by passing the list of services in the curl command like this: `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app?with=mysql,redis`. Thanks @apokryfos for the helpful comment. Once these containers are running, you can use VSCode (together with GIT) to connect to them and do your development work.

Of course, you can still use the old-school method of Laravel development. Just install XAMPP or one of its cousins on your machine and then use `composer create-project` command from the terminal to create it on your local file system. Then host your database and website on locally running instances of Apache and MariaDB.

I have yet to check out Bitnami Laravel image and how it works.